# Idiomatic way of creating an Entity with a JsonObject in RESTEasy?

Tags: java, json, resteasy

I'm hoping someone can clear up my confusion. I've got code working, but it's not what I expected. I'm trying to build a `Response` object in RESTEasy that returns a JSON entity. Here is what I got working:

```
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

// Works fine!
JsonObject jObj = makeMeMyJsonObject();
Response filteredResponse = Response.ok()
                                    .entity(jObj.toString())
                                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .build();
```

But that `toString` thing throws me for a loop. I expected to be able to do something more along the lines of this:

```
// Blows up!
JsonObject jObj = makeMeMyJsonObject();
Response filteredResponse = Response.ok()
                                    .entity(Entity.json(jObj))
                                    .build();
```

In other words, I thought I could simply pass the `entity` method a `JsonObject`. When I do that however, I get the following exception:

`org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity is not backed by an input stream`

Note: I am not trying to marshal a Plain Old Java object. I've already built a `JsonObject`. Is there a way to pass it directly to the `entity` method without having to convert it to a `String`? It's not a big deal, but if there is an idiomatic way of doing it, I'd like to do it that way. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24766636/1353722) might help.

Comment: Okay, I wondered if something like that was going on. It's not a big deal to use toString, and then manually set the Content-Type; I just thought the API might handle it. Thanks.